# Issue with GIT hosted on IIS with Bonobo

Tags: windows, git, iis-7, bonobo

We installed Bonobo Git Server on a webserver using IIS7.

Everything seems to work fine, we create repositories, we clone them, but when we try to push we have this error:

```
$ git push origin master
Username:
Password:
Counting objects: 3985, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3561/3561), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3984/3984), 24.67 MiB | 7.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 3984 (delta 645), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: <!DO
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Invalid argument
```

It happens when we do a big commit, usually our initial commit.

If I commit juste something like readme.txt it works just fine.

Most of our repos are migrations from SVN, we are working with it for about 2 weeks now and everything went great until we started a new project and made a big initial commit.

I did not manage to find anything useful by googling the error.

I also modified my git.config to this:

```
[http]
    postBuffer = 524288000
    sslVerify = false
```

But it does not solve my issue.

Thanks a lot,

Charles

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the problem...In fact it was in Bonobo Web.config file

I had to add the following line:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

in the node

```
<system.web>
```

Comment: My exact same issue, and it's now solved! Thanks a lot for sharing this!! [Reported it as a bug (kindaof)](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/pull/20).

Comment: I found that this section also needed a boost:  <system.webServer> <security> <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102400" />

Comment: I took it farther to 
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4194304" />

Comment: This worked for my other computer but not for my new one! So just to clarify, I noticed that bonobo has 2 Web.config files on in the actual root folder and one in App_Data. However the one in App_Data does not have a <system.web> node. Which one were you referring to?

Comment: Ahh! I missed out on modifying the git.config file like you mentioned!

Comment: Thought I might share this, as the above didn't fully resolve the issue I had. I had to run the following command:
**git config --unset http.postBuffer** , as reported in this [Issue](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/128)